# On iOS, is the current graphics context and context stack part of the application singleton?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

On iOS, there is a current graphics context and context stack, so we can push a context to the stack or pop from it, to change the current context.  Is this implemented as part of the application singleton object?  That is, when an app start to run, there is an application singleton that gets instantiated, and the context stack is a property of the app singleton? (or how is it implemented?)

Comment: You're talking about Core Graphics contexts, right? There are also OpenGL ES and Core Data contexts, among others, but it sounds like you're asking about Core Graphics ones.

Comment: Graphics contexts are part of the C API, and thus probably save state outside of the app's Objective C objects.

Comment: @Brad thanks, the question is modified to specify it

Comment: @Brad wow I saw your iTunes U videos before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that graphic context is a property of app singleton. CGContextRef it's an object which represents drawing environment. You can create new context for example to draw offline, you can get current context in drawRect: method ob UIView class.